# Unable to get the entire Image in web Api while doing Post from the MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Actually, I am Sending the Image as a memory stream from MVC controller to the Web API as a MemoryStream, while downloading the image in Web API,  I am just getting the half Image instead of full Image.[Please find the sample output Image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/330ZH.jpg)

my MVC controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach (string item in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (file.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:35221");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octent-stream"));
                HttpContent content = new StreamContent(ms);
                var response = client.PostAsync("Api/Ocr/GetText",content).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                }}}}
```

My Web API Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public List<string> GetText(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent content = Request.Content;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            content.CopyToAsync(ms);

            Stream stream = ms;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);



        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\bPopuri\Desktop\Test\Temp.jpg");

            byte[] value = memorystream.ToArray();

        }
```

Sorry Guys, I am unable to post my total code here. I am just sending the image from MVC to web API but the image in the web API is not loading properly.

Please help me how to avoid this problem.

Thanks in Advance for the help

Comment: Well you are using an `Async` method.  I'm guessing that it's not done copying before you try to use it.  You need to ensure the `Async` operation has completed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `await` your call to `CopyToAsync`. In order to do that, make the following changes:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetText(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    ...
    await content.CopyToAsync(ms);
    ...
}
```

It looks like the problem is due to the copy operation not completing before you attempt to save the file.